# Nullpointer Exception when loading WSDL file using org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.util.WSDLResourceImpl

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, emf

We are having a problem when we are loading a WSDL file using the org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.util.WSDLResourceImpl and have found a problem of Nullpointer Exception.

We have observed that the below code in org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.internal.impl.MessageImpl causes Nullpointer exception when the EMF models are initialized in one class loader and the second class loader calls the 
EMF WSDl loading.

```
public void handleUnreconciledElement(Element child, Collection remainingModelObjects)
  {
    switch (WSDLUtil.getInstance().getWSDLType(child))
    {
      case WSDLConstants.PART:
      {
    Part part = ((WSDLPackage)EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.getEPackage(WSDLPackage.eNS_URI)).getWSDLFactory().createPart();
    part.setEnclosingDefinition(getEnclosingDefinition());
    part.setElement(child);
    getEParts().add(part);
    break;
      }
      default:
      {
    super.handleUnreconciledElement(child, remainingModelObjects);
    break;
      }
    }
  }
```

The Nullpointer exception happens here

Part part = ((WSDLPackage)EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.getEPackage(WSDLPackage.eNS_URI)).getWSDLFactory().createPart();

because the registry does not have the entries of the WSDL Namespace URI for the second classloader

The stackTrace of the above issue is given below

```
MessageImpl.handleUnreconciledElement(Element, Collection) line: 411    
MessageImpl(WSDLElementImpl).reconcileContents(Element) line: 1296  
MessageImpl(WSDLElementImpl).reconcile(Element) line: 1242  
MessageImpl(WSDLElementImpl).changeAttribute(EAttribute) line: 1215 
MessageImpl.changeAttribute(EAttribute) line: 467   
MessageImpl(WSDLElementImpl).eNotify(Notification) line: 472    
MessageImpl(WSDLElementImpl).setElementGen(Element) line: 181   
MessageImpl(WSDLElementImpl).setElement(Element) line: 367  
DefinitionImpl.handleUnreconciledElement(Element, Collection) line: 1785    
DefinitionImpl(WSDLElementImpl).reconcileContents(Element) line: 1296   
DefinitionImpl(WSDLElementImpl).reconcile(Element) line: 1242   
DefinitionImpl(WSDLElementImpl).changeAttribute(EAttribute) line: 1215  
DefinitionImpl.changeAttribute(EAttribute) line: 1997   
DefinitionImpl(WSDLElementImpl).eNotify(Notification) line: 472 
DefinitionImpl.eNotify(Notification) line: 515  
DefinitionImpl(WSDLElementImpl).setElementGen(Element) line: 181    
DefinitionImpl(WSDLElementImpl).setElement(Element) line: 367   
DefinitionImpl.setElement(Element) line: 1704   
DefinitionImpl.createDefinition(Node, String, boolean) line: 1511   
WSDLResourceImpl.handleDefinitionElement(Element) line: 572 
WSDLResourceImpl.findDefinition(Element) line: 540  
WSDLResourceImpl.doLoad(InputSource, Map) line: 285 
WSDLResourceImpl.doLoad(InputStream, Map) line: 358 
WSDLResourceImpl(ResourceImpl).load(InputStream, Map<?,?>) line: 1505
```

The Scenario we have is we have one thread where the EMF WSDL model is initialized with Classloader 1. Next there is another thread which is making a call for the model WSDL file loading and there 
Classloader 2 is doing the loading. then we wee the below code in org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.internal.impl.MessageImpl fails with Nullpointer exception

Part part = ((WSDLPackage)EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.getEPackage(WSDLPackage.eNS_URI)).getWSDLFactory().createPart();

So it is clear that with two class loaders we cannot initialize the EMF models if the first time the EMF classes are loaded because second time the isInited is true and initialization is not done. The code 
snipped is shown below

```
 public static WSDLPackage init()
  {
    if (isInited)
      return (WSDLPackage)EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.getEPackage(WSDLPackage.eNS_URI);

    // Obtain or create and register package
    WSDLPackageImpl theWSDLPackage = (WSDLPackageImpl)(EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.getEPackage(eNS_URI) instanceof WSDLPackageImpl
      ? EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.getEPackage(eNS_URI) : new WSDLPackageImpl());

    isInited = true;

    // Initialize simple dependencies
    XSDPackage.eINSTANCE.eClass();

    // Create package meta-data objects
    theWSDLPackage.createPackageContents();

    // Initialize created meta-data
    theWSDLPackage.initializePackageContents();

    // Mark meta-data to indicate it can't be changed
    theWSDLPackage.freeze();

    return theWSDLPackage;
  }
```

Now the same problem does occur with XSD because when we use the org.eclipse.xsd.util.XSDResourceImpl to load an XSD file it come to the method below

XSDResourceImpl.handleSchemaElement(Element, boolean)

here the code is as given below

```
protected void handleSchemaElement(Element element, boolean isMeta)
  {
    XSDSchema xsdSchema;
    if (element == null)
    {
      xsdSchema = XSDFactory.eINSTANCE.createXSDSchema();
      xsdSchema.getQNamePrefixToNamespaceMap().put(null, XSDConstants.SCHEMA_FOR_SCHEMA_URI_2001);
    }
    else if (isMeta)
    {
      xsdSchema = XSDSchemaImpl.createMetaSchema(element);
    }
    else
    {
      xsdSchema = XSDSchemaImpl.createSchema(element);
    }
    getContents().add(xsdSchema);
  }
```

Here the XSDFcatory is used in the flowwing way

xsdSchema = XSDFactory.eINSTANCE.createXSDSchema();

So we wanted to know that why this code cannot be changed in org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.internal.impl.MessageImpl as given below which can fix the issue and also is consistent with the XSD behaviour

```
 public void handleUnreconciledElement(Element child, Collection remainingModelObjects)
   {
     switch (WSDLUtil.getInstance().getWSDLType(child))
     {
       case WSDLConstants.PART:
       {
     Part part = WSDLFactory.eINSTANCE.createPart();
     part.setEnclosingDefinition(getEnclosingDefinition());
     part.setElement(child);
     getEParts().add(part);
     break;
       }
       default:
       {
     super.handleUnreconciledElement(child, remainingModelObjects);
     break;
       }
     }
  }
```

Otherwise please let us know if there is another alternate solution for this issue. Clearly classloading causes issues in the EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE when multiple classloaders are present.

Also we have two doubts

1) Why the registry is per classloader. If that is the case then how can registry be populated for multiple classloaders as EMF once initialized the it does not allow to initialize again

2) Also in org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.internal.impl.MessageImpl why WSDFactory.eINSTANCE cannot be used instead of the registry

Please let us know as this very important for one of the projects we are working on. We need to have the solution with very high priority

Thanks and Regards
 Ananth